# How do I set this in Firefox? (open new stuff instead of old stuff)

Tags: windows, browser, firefox

When I open Firefox, it goes to what I closed it as.

I want it to open my home page and nothing else.
Not the stuff I closed it with.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to preferences - main. The first option selects what happens when Firefox opens. Choose "My home page".

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this page](http://www.davidtan.org/how-to-remember-reopen-closed-tabs-firefox/).
You can either reopen closed tags, or a homepage, or a blank page.
In my situation Firefox asks me every shut-down for what it should do. You can search for 'firefox ask to save quit' in google to find a solution to this.

(As a new user I'm not allowed to post more than 1 link)

Hope I could help you!

Comment: you can post additional links in comments until you earn more rep.